# Android setting Night Mode through AppCompatPreferenceActivity template cancels clicking on preference headers

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-night-mode

**My Goal**: Setting night mode through preferences and updating the UI in real time.

**So far**: Done. BUT when I click back to the headers' preference screen I cannot get back in the different preferences' screens again.

**To elaborate**: My settings are pretty simple at that point. I'm following the preset set by Android Studio (3.1.4) of SettingsActivity, having a template of AppCompatPreferenceActivity. I have one main screen and two deeper ones.

My first screen has two choices: General and About.
Upon selecting General, I load a GeneralPreferenceFragment with one Switch preference, that of "Night Mode".
If I set it on, it switches the theme real time and when I go back, it's also done on my first settings' screen.

**The problem:** When I do change the theme, go back to the main SettingsScreen and I try to revisit either General or About screens, I cannot go deeper any more! If I switch the preference an even number so that I end up to the initial theme, I can visit them like nothing has happened.

SettingsActivity class

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatPreferenceActivity() {

// To be used for live changes in night mode
private var mCurrentNightMode: Int = 0
private val TAG = "SettingsActivity"
private var mThemeId = 0

/**
 * Doing this hack to add my own actionbar on top since it wasn't there on its own
 */
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(TAG, "onPostCreate")

    val root = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.list).parent.parent.parent as LinearLayout
    val bar = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false) as Toolbar
    root.addView(bar, 0) // insert at top
    bar.setNavigationOnClickListener {finish()}
}

override fun setTheme(resid: Int) {
    super.setTheme(resid)
    mThemeId = resid
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (delegate.applyDayNight() && (mThemeId != 0) ) {
        // If DayNight has been applied, we need to re-apply the theme for
        // the changes to take effect. On API 23+, we should bypass
        // setTheme(), which will no-op if the theme ID is identical to the
        // current theme ID.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            onApplyThemeResource(theme, mThemeId, false);
        } else {
            setTheme(mThemeId);
        }
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("SettingsActivity", "onCreate")
    setupActionBar()

    // Storing the current value so if we come back we'll check on postResume for any changes
    mCurrentNightMode = getCurrentNightMode();
}

// Comparing current and last known night mode value
private fun hasNightModeChanged(): Boolean {
    return mCurrentNightMode != getCurrentNightMode()
}

private fun getCurrentNightMode(): Int {
    return resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
}

override fun onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume()

    // Self-explanatory. When I load back into this screen, if there's a change in the theme, load it back!
    if(hasNightModeChanged()) {
        recreate()
    }
}

/**
 * Set up the [android.app.ActionBar], if the API is available.
 */
private fun setupActionBar() {
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
override fun onIsMultiPane(): Boolean {
    return isXLargeTablet(this)
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
override fun onBuildHeaders(target: List<PreferenceActivity.Header>) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target)
}

/**
 * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
 * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
 */
override fun isValidFragment(fragmentName: String): Boolean {
    return PreferenceFragment::class.java.name == fragmentName
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment::class.java.name == fragmentName
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment::class.java.name == fragmentName
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment::class.java.name == fragmentName
            || AboutFragment::class.java.name == fragmentName
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
class GeneralPreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        findPreference("night_mode").setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
            val booleanValue = newValue as Boolean

            if(booleanValue) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }

            activity.recreate()
            true
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(Intent(activity, SettingsActivity::class.java))
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
 .
 .
 .
 companion object {
 // (didn't change anything here)
 }
```

The problem occurs I think on my "recreate" calls. It's like the preference list's onItemClickListener is null or something similar.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: Simplified, now all my logic in in SettingsActivity class, I needn't have it in the abstract class

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe that I solved it by adding delayedRecreate instead of recreate (was trying different things from another question - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631109/1562774)):

```
override fun onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume()

    // Self-explanatory. When I load back into this screen, if there's a change in the theme, load it back!
    if(hasNightModeChanged()) {
        delayedRecreate()
    }
}

private fun delayedRecreate() {
    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(this::recreate, 1)
}
```

However, I don't really like the flicker it does when the screen is a bit delayed in recreating. If anyone has any other clues, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: upon changing the theme, how do you do to also change it in the activity that launched the SettingsActivity when you go back?

Comment: I set a local variable in the onCreate of the activity:

`viewModel.mCurrentNightMode = getCurrentNightMode()`

`private fun getCurrentNightMode(): Int {
        return resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
    }`

and check if there's any change overriding the onPostResume() method:
`private fun hasNightModeChanged(): Boolean { return viewModel.mCurrentNightMode != getCurrentNightMode()    }`

if there's a change, I call recreate()

Comment: thanks, but, why do you execute the check in onPostResume and not in onResume?

Comment: @glisu It was a decision a while ago, there must have been a reason but now that I test it, I see that doing it in onResume() also works so the choice is yours!