# Android application theme change smoothly

Tags: android, styles, android-theme, theme-daynight

I am working on a project where day and night themes available.

I am changing themes by

night theme:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

day theme:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

But to see the changes in that activity/app, I need to restart app or recreaate that activity by `recreate()` but this is taking time and its not smooth like whatsApp or Telegram.

So how could I change theme of app smoothly that looks beautiful on theme change?

Comment: have the same problem, can't get ride if it , did you find any solution to change theme smoothly ?